# Excel: Copy Paste Multiple Instances One String

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a column containing the below values which need to be pasted in the next column say triple or more times depending on requirements. Already got an INDEX formula from another post that works but did not understand how does this work - `=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,CEILING(ROWS($B$2:$B2)/3,1),1)`. In the below example there are 3 values in column A and I need to triple the values in column B. Would be helpful if a VBA macro can be created too asking for input as in how many instances. Thank you!

[image: Sample]

Comment: the `/3` is how it creates instances of 3, using this formula the number of instances pcan be changed but would not be dynamic. i.e you couldn't use it to have 3 x ABC and then 4 x PQR

Comment: @PeterH: Got it, but do I need to paste the formula in column B i.e B2 cell and drag it down or any other column? What does `CEILING(ROWS($B$2:$B2)` do?

Comment: It will need to start in row 2.ROWS is counting the number of rows between B2 & B2, when dragged down it become B2 & B3. the /3 part breaks every 3 rows in to a .33333, CEILING rounds this up to the nearest 1, so it can be used by INDEX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub multies()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    x = Application.InputBox(prompt:="enter repetition factor", Type:=1)
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    k = 2
    For i = 2 To N
        v = Cells(i, 1).Value
        For j = 1 To x
            Cells(k, 2).Value = v
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works.

Comment: @Irvin  You are quite welcome!